# Android List Adapter Issue on SonyTV

Tags: android, listadapter, sony

This only happens on SonyTV box.  Here is a screen shot:

[image]

The first 2 items have a corner issue.  I removed the code that might have caused this with an image set to visible or invisible depending on the condition.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int right = 0, top = 0, bottom = 0;

        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.forecast_item, null);
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
            lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mHeight);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.dateText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.forecastDateText);
            holder.dayText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.forecastDayText);
            holder.img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.forecastItemIcon);
            holder.realfeelText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.forecastReelFeelText);
            holder.temperatureText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.forecastHiLoTemp);
//          holder.alarmIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_img);
            holder.hiLoLabel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.forecastHiLoLabel);
            view.setTag(holder);
            view.setLayoutParams(lp);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
        ForecastModel f = mForecastList.get(position);
        holder.dayText.setText(f.name);
        Utilities.resizeText(mBaseSize, mResizeFactor, 8, holder.dayText);
        holder.dateText.setText(Utilities.doDateConversion(f.date, mWd));
        String iconBuf = (f.iconCode.length() == 1) ? "0" + f.iconCode : f.iconCode;
        holder.img.setImageResource(Utilities.getDrawableId("icon_" + iconBuf));
        holder.temperatureText.setText(f.high + DEG + "/" + f.low + DEG);
        holder.realfeelText.setText(f.reelfeelhigh + DEG + "/" + f.reelfeellow + DEG);
        holder.hiLoLabel.setVisibility(mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage().contains(ENGLISH)
                ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

//        if (position < 3 && Alarms.hasAlarm(mWd.getCurrentWeatherDataModel(), f)){
//          holder.alarmIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        } else holder.alarmIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

       ...

        return view;
    }
```

Any ideas why this might be occurring?  This works when TV is set to 720p, but not 1080p. The "hourly" tab is a listAdapter too, but it works.

Comment: you work on the Accuweather TV app? neat.

Comment: I do indeed....and this code works on all but the SonyTV box. "All"  so far :)